# Smtp Email not send in live

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

In my project i sent email in live but its show the problem

```
public function send_mail($to_email, $mail_subject, $mail_message, $attachment='')
{

    $msg_body='
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <table width="80%" border="0" style="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
            </table></body></html>';
    $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
    $config['smtp_user']    = 'test@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass']    = 'Admin@123@';
    $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html
    $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('Test@test.com', 'www.test.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    exit;
}
```

i got an error like this

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function initialize() on a non-object in /
i initialize working fine. its work fine in my local server.

```
                <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

            <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

            <p>Severity: Notice</p>
            <p>Message:  Undefined property: airport_mailer::$email</p>
            <p>Filename: libraries/airport_mailer.php</p>
            <p>Line Number: 109</p>

            </div><br />
            <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function initialize() on a non-object in <b>/home/goairport/public_html
            /application/libraries/airport_mailer.php</b> on line <b>109</b><br />
```

Comment: Did you loaded email in server

Comment: post complete error on here

Comment: can you example spartan

Comment: post complete error of this `Fatal error: Call to a member function initialize() on a non-object in / i initialize working fine. its work fine in my local server`

Comment: Fatal error : added spartan

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to load `email library`. Just add this line before `$this->email->initialize($config);` to load your `email library`.

```
$this->CI->load->library('email'); OR
$this->load->library('email');
```

See Also: [CodeIgniter Sending Email](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/email.html)

Comment: i added can you sent the Email library file

Comment: can you clear if possible to call one library into other library?